# How to add a GET request endpoint without path parameters in elixir

Tags: get, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have following in my router `get "/flow/reserve/", FlowController, :set_flow_reserved`.
when a send a get request to that path, it matches "reserve" to id in path_params in conn. `path_params: %{"id" => "reserve"}`. and it gives Bad Request error. how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you post more of your routes? This sounds like you have `resources flow` or something similar somewhere

Comment: What url are you using in your get request?  What version of Phoenix?  How are you seeing the `path_params`?

Comment: *it matches "reserve" to id in path_params in conn* -- What code did you use to accomplish that?

Comment: yes I have `resources "/flow", FlowController, except: [:new, :edit]`

Comment: I'm using Phoenix v1.2.5 .

Comment: I inspected `conn` and it shows `{"id" => "reserve"}` in path_params

Answer (score 0):

The case you're getting because the order in your `router.ex` doesn't match the order from `action` in controller.

Let's say you have routes in this order:

```
  get "/flow/:id", FlowController, :edit
  get "/flow/reserve/", FlowController, :set_flow_reserved
```

so in your controller should be in the same order.

```
  def edit(conn, params)
  def set_flow_reserved(conn, params)
```

When a request is made, all request information from the `request path`( the route path when sending request) will be sent to controller and it will try to match to the `action` in controller. So in your case it will match `:id` to `reverse`

Comment: I don't think the order of the actions in the controller matters here, because the action names are different already. It *would* matter if both routes pointed to the same action. Your point about the order of the routes in the router still stands though.

Comment: Not the action name but the path he define. I believe he’s using the same path for *flow*

Comment: I have them in the correct order and my routes show it as `flow_path  GET      /api/flow/reserve                      MyApp.FlowController :set_flow_reserved`

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Can you edit your question to show the controller action and the routes?